# how to get tinytex to produce pdfs on rstudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, tinytex

I have intstalled tinytex and now I was trying to knitr my .rmd to .pdf but I find myself with this message:

```
output file: *_report.knit.md

tlmgr search --file --global "/multirow.sty"
Trying to automatically install missing LaTeX packages...
tlmgr install multirow
No connection to the internet.
Unable to download the checksum of the remote TeX Live database,
but found a local copy so using that.

You may want to try specifying an explicit or different CTAN mirror;
see the information and examples for the -repository option at
http://tug.org/texlive/doc/install-tl.html
(or in the output of install-tl --help).

tlmgr.pl: package repository http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: unknown)
[1/1, ??:??/??:??] install: multirow [3k]
TLPDB::_install_package: downloading did not succeed
tlmgr.pl: package log updated: C:/Users/***/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
tlmgr search --file --global "/multirow.sty"
! LaTeX Error: File `multirow.sty' not found.

! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

Error: Failed to compile *_report.tex. See *_report.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

I suppose that I did something wrong or I am missing some code, but after looking around I just admitted defeat,
any help much appreciated
thanks,

Comment: I see at the beginning of the message it says you don't have an internet connection. I could see not having an internet connection might be an issue if tinytex is trying to install missing Latex packages.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i was using internet at the moment and worked fine.

Comment: Are you using a proxy to connect to the internet?

Comment: this is my work computer, so I think so

Comment: In that case https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300552/tlmgr-proxy-on-windows might help. You will need to get information on the proxy from your IT department, though. BTW, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work might also be useful.

Comment: Thanks for that, I will try it